# Is there lore for Overwatch characters infinitely respawning?

Tags: overwatch

I know most of the lore for the game so far, but does any explain why it is reasonable for the characters to fight, if they always just respawn a few seconds later and rejoin the fight?

Comment: IIRC the entire game isn't considered lore (this also explains why for instance Tracer and Widowmaker can work in the same team even though they fought each other in the shorts)

Comment: That's one way to look at it.

Comment: Because heroes never die.

Comment: why does any hero in a game have the ability to die, and regenerate, providing they have an amount of "lives" left?

Comment: @Timelord64 Some games do provide an explanation for this, and given how lore heavy Overwatch is trying to be I don't feel this is unreasonable question.

Comment: Also, I see we're now up at two close votes. Honestly, I don't think this is  great question, but for the reasons I stated above I think it's perfectly on-topic. Remember, a close vote is not a super downvote.

Comment: I get that it isn't worded that great, but *it is* a **lore** question, not a **game design** question.

Comment: I disagree. I think we have a perfectly reasonable *base mechanic* that is obviously there to allow the game to *actually work*. While incredibly rare, one or two games do explain this in lore. But if we use that to allow any question asking to explain a basic game mechanic in lore, we open ourselves to many undesirable questions. "why am I allowed to respawn when I die in <any game you can think of that is not a diablo-hardcore mode>"? Even the answer, in this case, is entirely speculation. Otherwise, the poster would not have to state "unless were told otherwise", and "no reason to *assume*

Comment: Ultimately, we do not want questions that rely on answers that use assumption and a lack of knowledge as the basis on why they are currently "the best explanation you will get".

Comment: This is perfectly fine as a lore question. TF2 had their own in-universe lore that addressed classes respawning over and over, as well as in-game as well.

Comment: I also think that an answer as simple as "No" might very well be the answer to such questions, but it doesn't make the questions bad.

Comment: @Timelord64 to me, to be a Game design question, it has to be about why a choice was made. This question is asking if there's a lore explanation for a mechanic (and what that explanation is, by implication), not why the mechanic itself is in place.

Comment: I don't understand why a lore question wouldn't be allowed. On this site's tour ( http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour ) it mentions "Plot and characters in games" which sounds like lore to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The confrontations that happen in PVP matches are not canon. They're framed by the lore, but they can include clearly nonsensical things (Like 6 Lucios battling against another 6 Lucios). Certain characters have 0 reason to work together, like Tracer and Widowmaker, yet gladly do so.

Until we see otherwise, there's no reason to assume these PVP games are actually occurring in the Overwatch timeline. Think of it more as providing a backdrop.

Some of the characters, upon respawn, make mention of "the wonders of modern medicine". This is probably the best you will get for an explanation of the respawning in-game.

Comment: This perspective made me laugh. You're certainly right about the multiples.

Comment: They may just use the Halo method, where it's all just a simulation and doesn't matter.

Comment: I wouldn't say "gladlly do so", if I do recall there is a specific voice line that triggers between Tracer and Widowmaker in games which goes along the lines of "god why do I have to work with you" and tracer responds with something like "the feeling is mutual"

Answer (score 2):

There is one hero which the lore of OW does sort of support infinitely respawning -- [Reaper](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Reaper#Reaper):

> Reyes resurfaced as a volatile mercenary known as "Reaper." His
>   identity and motives remained unknown. Now a ruthless and remorseless
>   killer, he was responsible for terrorist attacks throughout the world.
>   He fought in many armed conflicts over the decades, showing no loyalty
>   to any cause or organization. Survivors described him as a black
>   shadow ghosting unscathed through the most hellish battlefields. The
>   few bodies recovered of his victims were pale, empty husks drained of
>   life, their cells showing signs of intense degradation. It was
>   speculated that Reaper was a byproduct of failed genetic alteration
>   which forced his cells to simultaneously decay and regenerate at a
>   hyper-accelerated rate.
>
> Those attempting to track his movements began to see a pattern in his
>   appearances. They believed that Reaper was hunting former Overwatch
>   agents and systematically eliminating them.

Keywords from the summary:

> speculated that Reaper was a byproduct of failed genetic alteration
>   which forced his cells to simultaneously decay and regenerate at a
>   hyper-accelerated rate.

This, in accordance with his interactions with Mercy supports that after the bombing of OW HQ, Reaper can constantly regenerate his cells even after he decays. Some quotes after he respawns are "*The grave cannot hold me back*" perhaps indicating he's done this before.